# Подскажите документацию на sqlite3.Binary, sqlite3.Error и прочее в dir(sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite3

Если посмотреть при помощи `dir(sqlite3)` список методов, то получим нечто:

```
dir(sqlite3)
Out[13]: 
['Binary',
 'Cache',
 'Connection',
 'Cursor',
 'DataError',
 'DatabaseError',
 'Date',
 'DateFromTicks',
 'Error',
 'IntegrityError',
 'InterfaceError',
 'InternalError',
 'NotSupportedError',
 'OperationalError',
 'OptimizedUnicode',
 'PARSE_COLNAMES',
 'PARSE_DECLTYPES',
 'PrepareProtocol',
 'ProgrammingError',
 'Row',
 'SQLITE_ALTER_TABLE',
 'SQLITE_ANALYZE',
 'SQLITE_ATTACH',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_INDEX',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_TABLE',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_INDEX',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TABLE',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TRIGGER',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_VIEW',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_TRIGGER',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_VIEW',
 'SQLITE_CREATE_VTABLE',
 'SQLITE_DELETE',
 'SQLITE_DENY',
 'SQLITE_DETACH',
 'SQLITE_DONE',
 'SQLITE_DROP_INDEX',
 'SQLITE_DROP_TABLE',
 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_INDEX',
 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TABLE',
 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TRIGGER',
 'SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_VIEW',
 'SQLITE_DROP_TRIGGER',
 'SQLITE_DROP_VIEW',
 'SQLITE_DROP_VTABLE',
 'SQLITE_FUNCTION',
 'SQLITE_IGNORE',
 'SQLITE_INSERT',
 'SQLITE_OK',
 'SQLITE_PRAGMA',
 'SQLITE_READ',
 'SQLITE_RECURSIVE',
 'SQLITE_REINDEX',
 'SQLITE_SAVEPOINT',
 'SQLITE_SELECT',
 'SQLITE_TRANSACTION',
 'SQLITE_UPDATE',
 'Statement',
 'Time',
 'TimeFromTicks',
 'Timestamp',
 'TimestampFromTicks',
 'Warning',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 'adapt',
 'adapters',
 'apilevel',
 'collections',
 'complete_statement',
 'connect',
 'converters',
 'datetime',
 'dbapi2',
 'enable_callback_tracebacks',
 'enable_shared_cache',
 'paramstyle',
 'register_adapter',
 'register_converter',
 'sqlite_version',
 'sqlite_version_info',
 'threadsafety',
 'time',
 'version',
 'version_info']
```

Подскажите, где найти документацию на верхнюю часть функций, не описанных в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). Ну например `sqlite3.Binary` и `sqlite3.Error` [встречаются](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25371636/how-to-get-sqlite-result-error-codes-in-python) в [ответах](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379166/writing-blob-from-sqlite-to-file-using-python) на *StackOverflow* без пояснения, а понять что и как не могу - т.к. почитать негде.  Был бы признателен за ссылку, поскольку help не очень продуктивен. Вот например:

```
 help(sqlite3.Binary)
Help on class memoryview in module builtins:

class memoryview(object)
 |  memoryview(object)
 |  
 |  Create a new memoryview object which references the given object.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __delitem__(self, key, /)
 |      Delete self[key].
 |  
 |  __enter__(...)
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self==value.
 |  
 |  __exit__(...)
 |  
 |  __ge__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self>=value.
 |  
 |  __getattribute__(self, name, /)
 |      Return getattr(self, name).
 |  
 |  __getitem__(self, key, /)
 |      Return self[key].
 |  
 |  __gt__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self>value.
 |  
 |  __hash__(self, /)
 |      Return hash(self).
 |  
 |  __le__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self<=value.
 |  
 |  __len__(self, /)
 |      Return len(self).
 |  
 |  __lt__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self<value.
 |  
 |  __ne__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self!=value.
 |  
 |  __repr__(self, /)
 |      Return repr(self).
 |  
 |  __setitem__(self, key, value, /)
 |      Set self[key] to value.
 |  
 |  cast(self, /, format, *, shape)
 |      Cast a memoryview to a new format or shape.
 |  
 |  hex(self, /)
 |      Return the data in the buffer as a string of hexadecimal numbers.
 |  
 |  release(self, /)
 |      Release the underlying buffer exposed by the memoryview object.
 |  
 |  tobytes(self, /)
 |      Return the data in the buffer as a byte string.
 |  
 |  tolist(self, /)
 |      Return the data in the buffer as a list of elements.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Static methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __new__(*args, **kwargs) from builtins.type
 |      Create and return a new object.  See help(type) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  c_contiguous
 |      A bool indicating whether the memory is C contiguous.
 |  
 |  contiguous
 |      A bool indicating whether the memory is contiguous.
 |  
 |  f_contiguous
 |      A bool indicating whether the memory is Fortran contiguous.
 |  
 |  format
 |      A string containing the format (in struct module style)
 |      for each element in the view.
 |  
 |  itemsize
 |      The size in bytes of each element of the memoryview.
 |  
 |  nbytes
 |      The amount of space in bytes that the array would use in
 |      a contiguous representation.
 |  
 |  ndim
 |      An integer indicating how many dimensions of a multi-dimensional
 |      array the memory represents.
 |  
 |  obj
 |      The underlying object of the memoryview.
 |  
 |  readonly
 |      A bool indicating whether the memory is read only.
 |  
 |  shape
 |      A tuple of ndim integers giving the shape of the memory
 |      as an N-dimensional array.
 |  
 |  strides
 |      A tuple of ndim integers giving the size in bytes to access
 |      each element for each dimension of the array.
 |  
 |  suboffsets
 |      A tuple of integers used internally for PIL-style arrays.
```

Comment: Пробовали использовать функцию `help`?

Comment: это не документация да и примеров там нет )